# clicking report activity nothing was happening in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code when clicking the report button not going to login activity even though it's not happening anything.
In login activity first of all I am checking the login username and password using session object.
if the username and password working fine and then want to move to next activity.

Can any one help me from this issue.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
report1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.report1);
        report=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.report);
        report1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        report.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

In the below when I am putting comment for session then it's moving but after entering the username and password it was showing logcat Admin user found but not going to next activity.it was staying in same activity itself.

**update Login**

```
public class Login extends Activity {
ImageButton login;
private static final Pattern USERNAME_PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,250}");
private static final Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+_.]{4,16}");
EditText usname,pword,ustype;
TextView tv,tv1;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
String username,password;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
String queryString;
String data="";
int i;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
CheckBox mCbShowPwd;
SessionManager session;
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog; 

 ConnectionDetector cd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
   // session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
   // session.checkLogin();


   // final HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();



    login = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.login);  

    usname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pword= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    ustype= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usertype);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    mCbShowPwd = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbShowPwd);
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
   mCbShowPwd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (!isChecked) {

                pword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            } else {

                 pword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    });


   login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           new LoadViewTask().execute(); 



           isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
           if (!isInternetPresent) {
               showAlertDialog(Login.this, "No Internet Connection",
                       "You don't have internet connection.", true);

               return;


           }

           String username = usname.getText().toString();
           String password = pword.getText().toString();

          // String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);


               if (username.equals("")) {
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER USERNAME",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
               if (password.equals("")) {
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER PASSWORD",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }

          else if (!CheckUsername(username) && !CheckPassword(password)){
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER VALID USERNAME & PASSWORD",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           else{
               queryString = "username=" + username + "&password="
                        + password ;
              String usertype = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("login",queryString);
              System.out.print(usertype);

        if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin user Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });


            Intent in=new Intent(Login.this, Reports.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }



        else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("No User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                     tv1.setText("InValid UserName and Password");

                }

            });
                    }


        }

       }


     });



}
private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>  
{  
    //Before running code in separate thread  
    @Override  
    protected void onPreExecute()  
    {  
         progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this,"Loading...",  
                "Loading application View, please wait...", false, false);  
      progressDialog.show(); 
    }  


    @Override  
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)  
    {  

        try  
        {  

            synchronized (this)  
            {  

                int counter = 0;  

                while(counter <= 4)  
                {  

                    this.wait(850);  

                    counter++;  

                    publishProgress(counter*25);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        catch (InterruptedException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  


    @Override  
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  
    {  

        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
    {  

        progressDialog.dismiss();  


    }  

}  

        private boolean CheckPassword(String password) {

            return PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(password).matches();
        }

        private boolean CheckUsername(String username) {

            return USERNAME_PATTERN.matcher(username).matches();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();


            alertDialog.setTitle(title);


            alertDialog.setMessage(message);


            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);


            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });


            alertDialog.show();
        }

}
```

Comment: check whether `Login` is defined in `manifest.xml `

Comment: of course it was defined in manifest if it is not defined it will give some unfortunately error

Comment: Are you using `Button` or `ImageView`

Comment: try to setClickable="true" in xml

Comment: @Nilesh see my updated login

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the application's context, use the context the view currently be presented.

```
   report.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```